# Как добиться однородного фона (TextView внутри CardView)?

Tags: android, android-layout

В моей программе мне нужно использовать `TextView` внутри `Cardview` из библиотеки поддержки. Нужны скругленные углы. Нужно иметь возможность изменять цвет элемента программно. Следующий код:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="31"
            android:textColor="#0f0"
            android:textSize="150sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

приводит к такому результату:

[image: фон в CardView]

Эти странные полосы и черточки меня совершенно не устраивают.

Следующий же код:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="31"
            android:textColor="#0f0"
            android:textSize="150sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

приводит к другому результату:

[image: Фон задан у TextView]

Второй результат мне не подходит из-за белых краев.

Третья моя попытка: 
Создала файл `rownded_corners.xml`  в папке `drawable`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

и в разметке второй попытки задала его в качестве фона `TextView`:

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
```

Вот что получилось:

[image: Фон из drawable]

Здесь меня не устраивает белая рамка.

В общем, вопрос:
Как мне добиться однородного цвета, заполняющего весь `CardView`, и сохранить возможность программно установить другой цвет.

UPDATE. Описанное в вопросе недоразумение уже разрешилось. См. мой ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Представляете, описанное в вопросе  недоразумение было вызвано тем, что используемый мною цвет (`colorPrimary`) был полупрозрачным (что-то вроде `#a03F51B5`) и через него была видна "кухня" построения `CardView`. Я изменила его  на `#3F51B5` и первый вариант дал желаемый результат даже без атрибута, предложенного @ЮрийСПб.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
```

или так:

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Я думаю, ваш совет эквивалентен моей первой попытке, описанной в вопросе. Или есть какая-то разница?

Comment: @iramm, и правда, хотя у меня работает такой способ

Comment: @iramm, а какая версия com.android.support:cardview-v7?

Comment: com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить вот этот атрибут в разметку карточки:

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Comment: Подстановка указанного атрибута во все 3 версии не изменила их результат.

Comment: @iramm, а вы на каком девайсе тестируете?..

Comment: На очень старом своем любимом Samsung Galaxy Ace (2.3.6). Так и быть попробую еще на чем-нибудь.

Comment: @iramm, хм... Да, лучше на чём-то поновее попробовать)

Comment: На Prestigio Multipap pmp5197d (4.0.3) то же самое

Comment: На Lenovo A319 (4.4.2) вариант 2 и 3 - те же. Первый вариант немного отличается, но все равно не то, что нужно.

Comment: @iramm, это всё очень странно... У меня всё без нареканий и чёрточек работает...Попробуйте либы поддержки и карточек обновить до `23.3.0`... У меня строит цвет в карточке, помянутый в ответе атрибут и всё... Может, надо ещё прозрачный фон для textView назначить?..

Comment: К сожалению обновление либ не помогло. Черточки имеются даже если карточка совсем пустая.

Comment: Все выяснилось. Черточки были вызваны использованием полупрозрачного цвета. Спасибо вам большое. Ваша уверенность, что все должно работать помогли мне.

Comment: @iramm, вот это поворот) Ну, и не такое бывает. Хорошо, что всё в итоге получилось)